# Is It Worthwhile To Have a Table That Only References Columns From Parent Table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I currently have a database for trading cards and the main table is AllCards. This table has twenty columns and has over millions of rows, but my question regards towards the column boolean type isSold in AllCards. Whenever a user loads our site, a query like `“select someColumns from AllCards where isSold = False”` is done to show all the available cards. However, I was wondering if it would be better to have a separate table labelled historic and current to not query millions of rows. My backend code will place cards that are not sold yet to Current and once sold, delete that row in Current and move that row to Historic.

```
Table Historic
Uid INT,
HCardID INT,
FOREIGN KEY Uid REFERENCES User(id),
FOREIGN KEY HCardID REFERENCES AllCards(cardID)

Table Current
Uid INT,
CCardID INT,
FOREIGN KEY Uid REFERENCES User(id),
FOREIGN KEY CCardID REFERENCES AllCards(cardID)
```

As shown above, Historic contains IDs to AllCards that have been sold and Current contains IDs to AllCards that have not been sold yet. Thus, when a user loads our site, I can just do a join query on table Current and iterate table AllCards where CardID = CCardID, instead of having to query through all rows of table All Events and check if it was sold or not. Is this a valid approach for performance and organization, or should I just forget about it, and only have an AllCards table and use the columns isSold? On the same topic, I also have implemented a table Week, a table with all the cards bought this week from a user. For this table I also do the approach of

```
Table Week
Uid INT,
WCardID INT,
FOREIGN KEY Uid REFERENCES User(id),
FOREIGN KEY WCardID REFERENCES AllCards(cardID)
```

This way, I do not have to query millions of rows to find cards that the user has bought this week and instead can do a join from Table Week and AllCards where cardID = WCardID and Uid = Uid. Does this help performance and organization and is this approach even worthwhile? Or should I just do go through rows in AllCards and do a query to get the same data for cards bough this week by the user?

Comment: If you do it like this, you have to watch out for errors that might leave things in an inconsistent state, where the same rows are in both `Historic` and `Current`. That can't happen if you just use a flag column in the main table.

Comment: @Barmar I agree that watching out for errors is an issue and that if I do decide to create `Historic` and `Current`, I am trading organization for speed. In your personal opinion, would you just use the `AllCard` table? I also had a question for `Week`. Does the same argument apply if I were to have a `LastWeek` and `ThisWeek` table? There could be inconsistencies in `LastWeek` when transferring the rows from `ThisWeek` to `LastWeek` and so if I just queried by dates in `AllCards`, there would never be wrong data? It just feels inefficient to query millions of rows for this data.

Comment: I would use the `AllCard` table, and put an index on the `isSold` column to make those queries efficient.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, and for `Week` and `LastWeek`, do you recommend to not use those tables and instead have an index on the bought date column in AllCards and get the last week and this week data from there? Thank you for the responses!

Comment: Yes, just index the date column. If there are performance issues if you need to join with these subqueries, you can make temporary tables by extracting the appropriate rows, then use these in the rest of the code.

Comment: How many rows in Historic vs Current?

Comment: What does "Uid" represent?

Comment: What happens if a card is traded multiple times?  Is it a new row each time?

Comment: @RickJames `Historic` is roughly 400,000 rows while `Current` is roughly 1.5 million rows right now. But in the future, as we get more sales and cards, I can see the numbers of rows flipping for the two tables, `Historic` having more rows than `Current` with both tables having millions of rows. Uid just represents User ID and references the column ID in table `User`. We currently do not do trading and the user can only sell and buy cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The week table should not exist.  Instead, have a datetime in AllCards and index it.

It is probably slower to go back and forth between Current and AllCards than to simply scan the entire AllCards.  Ditto for History.  Anyway, both are equivalent to having a pair of indexes on the big table.  I assume there is some column that distinguishes a "current" entity from a "history" entry in AllCards?

If the same "card" shows up again each time it is traded, then you might need a table of **Cards** (with 'card'-related columns) and a table of **Trades** (with trade related columns.  Trades would probably have UId and CCardId columns and the TradeDate, but Cards would not.  `TradeDate` would definitely be indexed, so you can get the week's trades efficiently.

Comment: The boolean column isSold in `AllCards` is used to distinguish if it is a "current" entity from a "history" entry. The reason why I am thinking of having these two tables is for speed purposes, as I feel it is inefficient to query millions of rows using `SELECT COLUMNS WHERE isSold = False` on `AllCards`, when I could just join query a separate table `Current` that has all the IDs of non-sold cards in `AllCards`, saving a large number of rows that I would not have to query.  You mentioned that a week table should not exist, however, what if I wanted all the cards bought for the year.

Comment: Should I just query the datetime column in AllCards, like you suggested for week data and not make a year table that has IDs of all the cards the user bought during that timeframe?

Comment: @JohnLewis - Fetching "millions" of rows will be either very slow or very-very slow.  Users will leave your web site out of boredom.  Or do you filter somehow?  Let's study the actual `SELECT` that you are hoping to speed up.

Comment: Week/year/l/month/black-friday/whatever -- having an index on the table will be _faster_ and _more flexible_ than having lots of week-like tables.

Comment: `WHERE user_id=123 AND purchate_date BETWEEN ...` will be very fast with `INDEX(user_id, purchase_date)`.  INDEXES!!!  Not extra tables!!!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but, I meant that the db would have to check millions of rows to get the rows that I want fetched when I do a query on `AllCards`. Whereas if I had a separate table `Current`, the db would have to check way less rows than `AllCards` when I do a query as only not sold cards are there. `AllCards` is the combination of sold cards and non-sold cards. Thus, leading me to ask if it is better to have separate tables of `Historic` (sold cards) and `Current` (non-sold cards) that references CardsIDs on `AllCards`. But, this way, querying would require join as they use CardIDs.

Comment: Currently, the SELECT query only fetches around 50,000-100,000 cards based on the type. However, as I get more cards, it would probably fetch way more than 100,000 per SELECT query. To combat with this, I would probably have to query in batches correct?

Comment: @JohnLewis - What do you do with those 100K rows?  Display them on a very long web page?  Or maybe 100 on each of 1000 web pages?  Sift through them looking for something?

Comment: I store them in an array and then index it via page number, 100 per page. However, I am changing this currently and instead of storing the result of the queries in an array, every time the user clicks on the next page, I just do a call to my backend to fetch the next 100 from the last id on the page before. I am doing this as when the result of the queries gets bigger, it is probably going to be impossible to store in an array.

Comment: @JohnLewis - Yes -- "remember where you left off".  And assuming you want to fetch in `id` order _and_ you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` [or some other usable index]`, _then_ it is always fast, wither it is a 1K rows or 1G rows.  You are never actually fetching all 100K rows, which _is slow_.